# iOS Enterprise distribution problem

Tags: ios

It was working but after releasing another build, OTA wireless installation started not working any more.. Giving me error saying Unable to Download App.. Used the exactly same provisioning profile and did everything same.. But it's not working..

Grab the logs from phone while I was trying to install

```
Sep 22 12:16:51 Wills-iPhone lockdownd[17] <Error>: 2ff15000 handle_connection: Could not receive USB message #6 from iPhone Configuration Utility. Killing connection

Sep 22 12:16:52 Wills-iPhone installd[608] <Error>: entitlement 'keychain-access-groups' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Sep 22 12:16:52 Wills-iPhone installd[608] <Error>: entitlement 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Sep 22 12:16:52 Wills-iPhone installd[608] <Error>: entitlement 'com.apple.developer.ubiquity-kvstore-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Sep 22 12:16:52 Wills-iPhone installd[608] <Error>: entitlement 'application-identifier' has value not permitted by a provisioning profile

Sep 22 12:16:52 Wills-iPhone installd[608] <Error>: 2ffc4000 verify_signer_identity: Could not copy validate signature: -402620394

Sep 22 12:16:52 Wills-iPhone installd[608] <Error>: 2ffc4000 preflight_application_install: Could not verify executable at /var/tmp/install_staging.DCVRV3/foo_extracted/Payload/ON Test.app

Sep 22 12:16:52 Wills-iPhone installd[608] <Error>: 2ffc4000 install_application: Could not preflight application install

Sep 22 12:16:52 Wills-iPhone installd[608] <Error>: 2ffc4000 handle_install: API failed

Sep 22 12:16:52 Wills-iPhone com.apple.itunesstored[606] <Notice>: MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to http://developer.apple.com/ios/ and make sure the certificate has not been revoke or expired on Apple's end.

Comment: Did it from a scratch and found that I was using wrong provisioning profile.. Thanks :)